# Calculate arbitrary digits of Pi (e.g. from 1000 - 2000) without calculating the first 1000 digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

Say I want to use an algorithm to generate the digits of pi. I can do this with various infinite series or whatnot .. but let's say I only want the 1000th - 2000th digits of pi, without wasting processing time on the first 1000 digits. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful but you can extract any single hexadecimal digit as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_%CF%80). It's probably faster to calculate the first $2000$ digits and remove the first $1000$ after this is done.

Comment: Probably no, such a method is only known for the binary digits of $\pi$, but even this method does not give the digit "at once", just faster.